# jQuery Regular Expression Checking User Input for Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to have it so when a user enters a string in the txtNmr field, they get an output saying enter a number. Currently, what I have isn't working correctly, and I can't get anything to print out. I know there are other ways in doing, but I want to use a regular expression.

```js
    function greetMe() {
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "white");
    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var nr = document.getElementById("txtNmr").value;
    $("#errors").empty();
    $("#greetings").empty();
    
    found_position = txtNmr.search(/\d/);
    if (found_position = -1){
      $("#errors").append("Enter a number not a string");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
    
if (nr > 0 && nr < 21) {
    for (var counter = 0; counter < nr; counter = counter + 1) {
      $("#greetings").append("Hello, " + name + "<br />");
    }
  } else {
    $("#errors").append("Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 20");
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type in your name</p>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<p>Enter a number 1-20.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtNmr">
<input type="button" value="Greet Me!" onclick="greetMe()">
<hr>
<div id="greetings">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
<div id="errors">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
```

Comment: To check if a string matches a regular expression, you can use `txtNmr.match(/\d/)` or you can use `/\d/.test(txtNmr)` (which will return true/false depending on if the string matches regex)

Answer (score 1):

`/^\d$/` means `'0'` or `'1'` or `'2'` or `'3'` or `'4'` or `'5'` or `'6'` or `'7'` or `'8'` or `'9'`. Any string different than this would be rejected, so `'10'` for example is rejected.

To add the remaining numbers `10` thorough `20`, you can change the reg exp to: `/^\d{1,2}$/`, which means any string composed by one to two digits, so the following is valid: `'01'`, `'2'`, `'15'`, `'84'`...

Note that I added the `^` which means that the string must start with, and `$` which means the string must end with.

Also I think there is a mistake in your code, it should be:

```
found_position = nr.search(/\d/);
```

Instead of:

```
found_position = txtNmr.search(/\d/);
```

So with the correct reg exp:

```
found_position = nr.search(/^\d{1,2}$/);
```

Another mistake, the test condition isn't correct:

```
if (found_position = -1)
```

Should be:

```
if (found_position == -1)
```

Note the double `==`

Answer (score 0):

You are just testing if the string starts with a number, you need to check if its all numbers.

Regex explained: https://regexr.com/42t4f

```js
    function greetMe() {
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "white");
    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var nr = document.getElementById("txtNmr").value;
    $("#errors").empty();
    $("#greetings").empty();
    
    if (/^\d+$/.test(nr) === false){
      $("#errors").append("Enter a number not a string");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
    
if (nr > 0 && nr < 21) {
    for (var counter = 0; counter < nr; counter = counter + 1) {
      $("#greetings").append("Hello, " + name + "<br />");
    }
  } else {
    $("#errors").append("Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 20");
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type in your name</p>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<p>Enter a number 1-20.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtNmr">
<input type="button" value="Greet Me!" onclick="greetMe()">
<hr>
<div id="greetings">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
<div id="errors">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to check if a string matches a regular expression.

[`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) finds the index of the match within a String which is not a good indicator of whether or not the String actually matches the regular expression.

To match only whole numbers, you should use the regular expression `/^\d+$/`

Also, you should put an `if`/`else` around the first condition that the input should be numeric. Otherwise, it will still print the greeting after the error message that the input should be a number.

```js
 function greetMe() {
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "white");
    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var nr = document.getElementById("txtNmr").value;
    $("#errors").empty();
    $("#greetings").empty();
    
    var found = nr.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (!found){
      $("#errors").append("Enter a whole number, not a string or a decimal");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else {
      if (nr > 0 && nr < 21) {
       for (var counter = 0; counter < nr; counter = counter + 1) {
          $("#greetings").append("Hello, " + name + "<br />");
       }
    } else {
      $("#errors").append("Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 20");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type in your name</p>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<p>Enter a number 1-20.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtNmr">
<input type="button" value="Greet Me!" onclick="greetMe()">
<hr>
<div id="greetings">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
<div id="errors">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
```

Without Regex, you convert the string to a number and then round it down and then check if the rounded number converted to a string is equal to the original string and that the number is larger than or equal to 0.

```
function isPositiveInteger(str) {
    var n = Math.floor(+str);
    return n !== Infinity && String(n) === str && n >= 0;
}
```

```js
 function greetMe() {
    $("#errors").css("background-color", "white");
    var name = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
    var nr = document.getElementById("txtNmr").value;
    $("#errors").empty();
    $("#greetings").empty();
    if (!isPositiveInteger(nr)){
      $("#errors").append("Enter a whole number, not a string or a decimal");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else {
      if (nr > 0 && nr < 21) {
       for (var counter = 0; counter < nr; counter = counter + 1) {
          $("#greetings").append("Hello, " + name + "<br />");
       }
    } else {
      $("#errors").append("Please Enter A Number Between 1 and 20");
      $("#errors").css("background-color", "yellow");
    }
  }
}
function isPositiveInteger(str) {
    var n = Math.floor(+str);
    return n !== Infinity && String(n) === str && n >= 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Type in your name</p>
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<p>Enter a number 1-20.</p>
<input type="text" id="txtNmr">
<input type="button" value="Greet Me!" onclick="greetMe()">
<hr>
<div id="greetings">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
<div id="errors">
  <!-- Section to output the greeting -->
</div>
```